# How to create queue in EmbeddedActiveMQBroker?

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

Im using EmbeddedActiveMQBroker and wonder, how to create queue for Spring test?
Tried this, but failed :

```
getBrokerService().setDestinations(new ActiveMQQueue[] {new ActiveMQQueue("reply-queue")});
```

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using? What exactly failed? Did you receive an exception or an error message in the log? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queues and Topics are auto-created by default. Simply start the broker and client connections will create the destinations for you.

If you really must have the destination to exist before the client connection, you can use brokerService.getAdminView().addQueue(String queueName)